# Firebase data default values

Tags: firebase

I have some columns that I would need default values without any kind of user intervention/alteration such as order status and some timestamps, user status (active, inactive, suspended etc).

Is there a way I could specify such columns with default data? Maybe in the `rules.json` or somewhere.

For example I have some orders from users. Before the money are sent I add the order as `pending` so I can have a reference on IPN. I don't want the user to be able to alter that field so in my rules I add `".validate": "newData.isString() && newData.val() == 'pending'"` but I want to allow a rest client to alter it's value to `completed` or `failed` etc. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a secret generate from the Forge for your Firebase and bypass the security rules from your REST client. Just pass the key as the "auth" parameter as documented here: https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest-api.html

Be careful, the REST client will be able to read and write to any location in the Firebase, so only store the secret on a secure server that runs your script.